# How do I know who made a post Community Wiki from the Stack Overflow data dump?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki, data-dump

Is it possible to determine who made a post closed or community wiki and why from the Stack Overflow data dump?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede)

Comment: @rene Isn't it PostHistory type 16, check the relevant UserId?

Comment: @ SonictheAnonymousHedgehog- it does not say anything about the person or reasons behind the community wiki post. I don't want to go through revision to look for that.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog probably but you know better under which conditions posts get cw-ed, including the history of that feature. You might check if I got that wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find that record in the PostHistory table by looking for rows with PostHistoryTypeId = 16

That row will have the UserId populated.

- When the UserId = -1 the post was made Community Wiki by the system.
- If the UserId == Posts.OwnerUserId the OP made the Post community wiki
- If the UserId != Posts.OwnerUserId either a moderator converted the post to Community Wiki or the question received its 30th answer (in which case the UserId is that of the answers OwnerUserId)

Here is a [SEDE Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/924472) to verify.

For closed questions you'll be looking at PostHistoryTypeId=10 where the `text`  column will have the JSON with all the close voters. The `UserId`  column will have the last close voter.

Comment: When you refer to the system, I assume you refer to the background process (Community User). I know there were automatic triggers that make the question community wiki (such as received the 30'th answer but instead of assigning the user id to the community user, the user id is set to the 30'th answer's OwnerUserId).  In which situations user id's were set to the system?